# TypeError: original_sum() missing 1 required positional argument: 'original_price'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner python programmer who has just started out with competitive programming. My program is running into some sort of problem which I could not rectify. Can somebody please help me what am I doing wrong here?

```
def limited_price_sum(limit_on_price):
    less_or_equal = []
    more = []
    limited_price = 0
    for items in original_price:
        if original_price[items] <= limit_on_price:
            less_or_equal.append(original_price[items])
        else:
            more.append(original_price[items])
    more[:] = [(mor - limit_on_price) for mor in more]

    final_limited_price_list = less_or_equal + more

    for num in range(0, len(final_limited_price_list)):
        limited_price += final_limited_price_list[num]

    return limited_price
```

Comment: Captain did this answer your question or are you running into more errors?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you David Erickson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include an argument `original_price` when calling `original_sum()` in this line of code `return original_sum() - limited_price_sum()`, so for example `original_sum(10)` which is the same thing as saying `original_sum(original_price=10)`.

You will need to do the same for `limited_price_sum()` and pass whatever the `limit_on_price` is. The main problem is that you are not passing the parameter/argument that is required in order to run the function!